# Ipd matching query does not exist in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I am trying to get objects from ForeignKey using QS but I can't seem to find a problem

**views.py:**

```
@login_required
    def ipd (request,patient_id):
        formtwo = IpdForm()
        qs = Ipd.objects.get(patient=patient_id)
        if request.method=="POST":
            formtwo = IpdForm(request.POST)

            if  formtwo.is_valid() :
                instance = formtwo.save(commit=False)
                instance.save
            else:
                return HttpResponse(formtwo.errors) 
        else:
            formtwo = IpdForm()
            return render(request, 'newipd.html', {'a':qs,'form2':formtwo})
```

**html:**

```
    <div class="card-panel">                                                         
    <span class="blue-text text-darken-2">Name : {{a.name}}</span> <br>                                                          
    <span class="blue-text text-darken-2">Phone : {{ a.phone  }}</span><br>                                                          
    <span class="blue-text text-darken-2">Address : {{ a.address  }}</span> 
   <br>                                                          
    <span class="blue-text text-darken-2">Gender : {{ a.Gender  }}</span><br>                                                        
   </div>
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from orders import views as my_order
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^$', my_order.index, name='home'),
    url(r'^orders$', my_order.index, name='home'),
    url(r'^order/(?P<patient_id>\d+)/$', my_order.show, name='show'),
    url(r'^order/new/$', my_order.new, name='new'),
    url(r'^order/ipd/(?P<patient_id>\d+)/$', my_order.ipd, name='ipd'),
    url(r'^order/edit/(?P<patient_id>\d+)/$', my_order.edit, name='edit'),
    url(r'^order/delete/(?P<patient_id>\d+)/$', my_order.destroy, 
name='delete'),
    url(r'^ipdlist$', my_order.ipd_list, name='ipd_list'),
    url(r'^users/login/$', auth.LoginView.as_view, {'template_name': 
'login.html'}, name='login'),
    url(r'^users/logout/$', auth.LogoutView.as_view, {'next_page': '/'}, 
name='logout'),
    url(r'^users/change_password/$', login_required(auth.PasswordResetForm), 
{'post_change_redirect' : '/','template_name': 'change_password.html'}, 
name='change_password'),
]
```

I am unable to find what is error with my code, I am new to Django and need Help in finding my answer!

Comment: add your `urls.py` here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To query with `foreign key` on patient field you need to use **`patient__Patient_id=patient_id`** instead of `patient=patient_id`.

And also you should use `filter()` instead of `get()` coz one-to-many relationship and hence 1 patient can have more than 1 Ipd.

```
qs = Ipd.objects.filter(patient__Patient_id=patient_id)
```

Comment: Thank You Sir ! I have tried patient__id=patient_id but now getting error "Related Field got invalid lookup: id
"

Comment: Sorry, you should use `filter()` instead of `get()` coz one to many relationship and 1 patients can have more than 1 Ipd. See updated answer.

Comment: Sorry Sir! but Still same error "Related Field got invalid lookup: id "

Comment: Sorry, your primary key is different than default, I was assuming primary_key to be `id` and hence it was giving error. Check the updated answer it will work.

Comment: Thank you Sir! the errors are gone, but still something is there, now the form is not showing any details of Patient object

Comment: There might be some different error, you can post as new question.

Comment: Is there any problem with context?

Comment: Thank You Very Much! for your help sir

Comment: @VickyRathod, you can select the answer. If it has resolved your query. Thanks.

Comment: Hello Sir! I think I was unable to explain the right problem of mine, I am having two form one creates patient object and another form is related to patient which contains patient info. I have not created any Ipd Object yet, that query will not work for that, I want to add patient object in my new Ipd Form ,Can You Help me with that I have been searching for an answer from a long time, Please Help Me